# Access FormData Values

Tags: javascript, php, web, xmlhttprequest, form-data

I'm trying to send an XHR request to a PHP page with several parameters (2 string, 1 blob) but I am unnable to get theses values in the PHP code..

here is my code :

**JS**

```
function initRequeteUpdImg(blob, file)
{
    img = document.getElementById("id");

    img.src = blob;

    requeteUdpRec = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
    requeteUdpRec.onreadystatechange = callback_ReqUpdRec;
    requeteUdpRec.open("POST","function/Modify_action.php", true);
    requeteUdpRec.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    
    function readFile(event) 
    {
        var fileType = file.type;
        blob = blobUtil.arrayBufferToBlob(event.target.result, fileType);

        formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("id", id);
        formData.append("action", "updImg");
        formData.append("file", event.target.result);

        requeteUdpRec.send(formData);
    }

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener('load', readFile);
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)
}
```

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST["action"]) && $_POST["action"]=="updImg")`{
    $requete = "select eleve_id from eleves where person_id = ?";
    $req_args = array($_POST['id']);
    $req_type = "i";
    $res = mysqli_fetch_array(prepared_query($requete, $req_args, $req_type));

    $requete = "update signature SET signature_blob = '".$_POST["file"]."' where eleve_id = ".$res["eleve_id"];

    $res = unprepared_query($requete, $req_args, $req_type);
}

else
{
    http_response_code (404);
}`
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong but where..?

I'm new to JS so if you could detail it would be very nice !
Thanks for your help !

**EDIT :**

Return of var_dump($_POST) :

```
array(1) {
  ["------WebKitFormBoundaryKNMixbnGfrQKo4ox
Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name"]=>
  string(265) ""id"

8
------WebKitFormBoundaryKNMixbnGfrQKo4ox
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="action"

updImg
------WebKitFormBoundaryKNMixbnGfrQKo4ox
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"

[object ArrayBuffer]
------WebKitFormBoundaryKNMixbnGfrQKo4ox--
"

}
```

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_POST);` to see what is coming in. Also better use prepared statements to prevent SQL injections.

Comment: Is `blob` a blob or a blob url? you use it as both.

Comment: blob is a blob,
i'll try the var_dump when i will have 5 minutes

Thanks for your reply

Comment: @MarkusZeller yes i've removed the prepared query here to simplify the code i've edit the post with the var_dump($_POST);